# Excel - A row in my pivot table gives a duration different from the actual table duration

Tags: excel, pivot-table

The first image below shows two highlighted rows in color red, this is because the duration for each team member starts at a particular time the same day and ends at different times the next day.

[image: link to first image since I am not allowed to post images yet.]

The second image below shows how the sum of duration is appearing for the team members highlighted in red. As you can see the value in the pivot table doesn't match the ones in the actual table itself. Please I would like to know the reason for this difference.

[image: link to second image since I am not allowed to post images yet]

Also just to note, my cells for duration in the pivot table are in the format [hh]:mm:ss

Comment: Was the Duration field filled or calculated? If calculated, what formula are you using?

Comment: Seems that in the date you have changed values for month and day.

Comment: @MagnoCorrea I just filled the field randomly.

Comment: @Blackcat please what do you mean by this?

Comment: Seems that date format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @Blackcat Yes that is what the date format is. How is this affecting the data in the pivot table....I will appreciate your further assistance.